# Overriding __iadd__ from the right hand side in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

Imagine I have a class `A` that is outside of my control (`numpy.ndarray` is the specific application), and class `B` within my control (`scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`). I want to implement in-place addition of `B` to `A` without touching class `A`.

Is this at all possible? Is it a bad idea? If this isn't possible in general, is it possible with numpy arrays specifically?

For a specific example consider:

```py
class A:
   foo = 0

   def __iadd__(self, other):
       print("Avoid calling this function.")
       return self

class B:
   def __add__(self, other):
       if isinstance(other, A):
           other.foo += 1
           return other

   __radd__ = __add__

   # Modify this class to make assertion below pass

a1, a2 = A(), A()
a1 += B()
a2 = a2 + B()
assert a1.foo == a2.foo == 1, "How to make this work"
```

EDIT: Actual application.

In-place addition of a sparse coordinate matrix to a dense numpy array has an efficient implementation:

```py
from time import time

import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

N = 1000
a = np.zeros((N, N))
b = sparse.identity(N, format="coo")

t_slow = -time()
a += b  # Want to override, converts b to array—slow!
t_slow += time()

t_fast = -time()
a[b.row, b.col] += b.data  # Desired implementation
t_fast += time()
print(f"{t_slow=:.2}s, {t_fast=:.2}s")
# t_slow=0.0017s, t_fast=0.00024s
```

Comment: In reality are you only adding a scalar "1" to the left-hand side? If not, what is the actual addition being performed?

Comment: Added the actual application to the post body.

Comment: I would consider it a *very* bad idea for `B.__add__` to mutate the *other* argument.  If I'm defining `A`, I don't expect `c = a + b` to modify `a` in-place.

Comment: Also, you aren't correctly defining your dunder methods. For example, your `A. __add__` will return `None` if the condition is false. It should return `NotImplemented` in that case

Comment: The minimal example is for illustration purposes only, it only demonstrates what needs to be overridden/implemented. I am aware of the problems you bring up.

Comment: @chepner, the sparse implementation of `a+=b` (`_add_dense`) does not work in-place. `b` ends up in control, changing `a` to `np.matrix`, and even changing its `dtype`.  It isn't a very well behaved method!

Answer (score 0):

The delegation from `iadd` to `radd` and on can be complicated

Look at a simple example.

```
In [237]: M=sparse.coo_matrix(np.eye(3))
In [238]: M
Out[238]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [239]: A = np.zeros((3,3))
In [240]: A
Out[240]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
In [241]: A + M         # a conventional add - makes a np.matrix
Out[241]: 
matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
In [242]: A += M
In [243]: A             # this too is np.matrix!
Out[243]: 
matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.]])
```

But if I convert sparse to add, the result is array:

```
In [244]: A = np.zeros((3,3))
In [246]: A += M.A
In [247]: A
Out[247]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

I suspect (but don't quote me on this)

```
A.__iadd__(M) =>
M.__radd__(A) =>
M.__add__(A) =>
M._add_dense(A) =>

def _add_dense(self, other):
    if other.shape != self.shape:
        raise ValueError('Incompatible shapes ({} and {})'
                         .format(self.shape, other.shape))
    dtype = upcast_char(self.dtype.char, other.dtype.char)
    result = np.array(other, dtype=dtype, copy=True)
    fortran = int(result.flags.f_contiguous)
    M, N = self.shape
    coo_todense(M, N, self.nnz, self.row, self.col, self.data,
                result.ravel('A'), fortran)
    return matrix(result, copy=False)
```

That would explain the `np.matrix` return.  Normally I don't expect `A+=...` to change `A` shape, class, or dtype.  But it looks like `sparse.coo` takes control.  I haven't looked at that `coo_todense`.

There some other evidence.  `A+=M` can change the dtype, while `A+=M.A` cannot.  `A+=M.A` is a `view`, `A+=M` is not.

So you might be able to modify the `sparse.coo_matrix` methods to do things as you want.  In fact, I could imagine submitting a bug issue for this sparse behavior.  Not only is it slower, but it changes `A` in non-numpy standard ways.

But why not just write a simple utility function, and not bother with the `+=` overwrite?

```
In [249]:     def add_to_dense(a,b):
     ...:         a[b.row, b.col] += b.data
     ...: 
In [250]: add_to_dense(A,M)
In [251]: A
Out[251]: 
array([[2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2.]])
```

Comment: My goal is overriding the implementation of in-place addition from the right hand side class. A helper function/method is an obvious alternative, but it doesn't achieve the same goal.

Comment: My function does work in-place.  I tested that with `__array_interface__`.  But as I showed the current sparse version does not operate in-place.

Comment: I don't follow: the code you provided seems to allow to call `a[b.row, b.col] += b.data` when `a += b` is invoked (which is what I aim to achieve).

Answer (score 0):

If you want `a += b` to work, define a way to *explicitly* convert `b` to a value that *does* work with `A.__iadd__`. Otherwise, you are opening the door for something like `c = a + b` to modify `a` in-place, which is probably going to lead to some hard-to-find bugs.

If there are types `D` for which for which `a += d` (`d` being an instance of `D`), then let `B` provide a way to turn an instance of `B` into an instance of `D`.

```
class B:
    def to_d(self):
        return ...

a += b.to_d()
```

Comment: That doesn't work: by my conditions the class A is outside of my control and doesn't implement the desired functionality.

Comment: I didn't do anything *to* `A`; I am suggesting changes to `B` based on the public interface of `A`.

Comment: I am interested in the case when `A` has no suitable public interface and `B` must provide the necessary functionality.

Comment: That sounds entirely broken.